# Why do these datetime conversions using pytz not land on hours before December of 1901?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Perhaps I am not using the libraries correctly, or perhaps there was some kind of standard change on December 15, 1901 concerning world wide time keeping. But I stumbled across this odd behavior while working on a time related application.

```
sydney = pytz.timezone("Australia/Sydney")
tokyo = pytz.timezone("Japan")
new_york = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")

dt1 = datetime(1901, 12, 14)
dt2 = datetime(1901, 12, 15)

print("-" * 50)
print(sydney.localize(dt1).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
print(tokyo.localize(dt1).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
print(new_york.localize(dt1).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
print("-" * 50)
print(sydney.localize(dt2).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
print(tokyo.localize(dt2).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
print(new_york.localize(dt2).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
print("-" * 50)
```

I expected this code to tell me the UTC equivalent of the midnight times in these different time zones. What I found odd was that for older datetimes before Dec 1901 the results were not even falling on the hour but had minute components. After Dec 1901 it seems every conversion ended up being on the hour. Here is the output of the code above:

```
--------------------------------------------------
1901-12-13 13:55:00+00:00
1901-12-13 14:41:00+00:00
1901-12-14 05:00:00+00:00
--------------------------------------------------
1901-12-14 14:00:00+00:00
1901-12-14 15:00:00+00:00
1901-12-15 05:00:00+00:00
--------------------------------------------------
```

Wondering if I am not using a reliable technique or if this is actually correct due to some historical/political reason?

Comment: Note, for New York on Dec 13th, 1901 it converts to 4:56 am rather than 5:00 am.

Comment: UTC wasn't official until 1960.  Timezone rules are notoriously difficult across the world.  See the data within the files at https://www.iana.org/time-zones as there is a huge amount of historical variation.  I see no information for Australia prior to 1917.  Can you explain what you're doing that requires this level of precision from 120+ years ago?

Comment: For very old times PTZ uses the actual timezone of the location to the minute since there where no timezones yet back then

Comment: @stdunbar I don't really need to handle times before 1990 in this application. Specifically the conversions are concerned with when forex trading sessions start and end. For example the Sydney session starts on weekdays at their local 8am, so I want to convert that to UTC to compare to market data which is all in UTC and so forth. All the market data is for after 1990.

Comment: Looks like the same issue raised here https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/77 - though it's not very clear where that transition date comes from. My naive reading of the ref data (which must be wrong) suggests the transition should happen in 1895: https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/1acdc7f5ab3f4af063ddcd435f79a48a4a8ce079/tz/australasia#L184

Comment: @slothrop well he seems to be using the same technique I did, which gives me more confidence I am using the library correctly for my purpose. Figure I will just consider dates before say 1970 to be invalid for my application and only unit test on times after that and I should be good (only found this odd behavior due to unit testing back to the year 2).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), though I'm not sure how exactly. 1901-12-13 20:45:52 UTC is `2**31` seconds before the Unix epoch, and if we look at that time for London, it's a minute off before.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

london = pytz.timezone("Europe/London")

dt0 = datetime(1901, 12, 13, 20, 45, 52)
second = timedelta(seconds=1)
for d in dt0-second, dt0, dt0+second:
    c = london.localize(d).astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    print(d, "|", c.time())
```

```
1901-12-13 20:45:51 | 20:46:51
1901-12-13 20:45:52 | 20:45:52
1901-12-13 20:45:53 | 20:45:53
```

---

By the way, note that these examples were all already using standard time based on GMT by 1901. On the other hand, Portugal for example only adopted it as of 1912-01-01, so doesn't show the same behaviour.

Comment: There is definitely some use of 32-bit C ints in pytz: https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/1acdc7f5ab3f4af063ddcd435f79a48a4a8ce079/tz/asctime.c

Comment: in support of your hypothesis: if I run your code with [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) timezones, output is as expected. Potentially, the "y2k38" issue goes back to https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/31